# Fatal error: 'Pixate/PXVirtualControl.h' file not found

Tags: ios, pixate

I am using the pixate framework to style my views. It does very well.
I am also using kiwi as a test framework. When I include the pixate framework for a test case it just throws the following error:

**fatal error: 'Pixate/PXVirtualControl.h' file not found**

**PXVirtualControl.h** is  a private header file.

Comment: Is Pixate installed directly to the project, or is it installed via Cocoapods?

Comment: I am using CocoaPods. From cocoapods the PrivateHeaders are also not being added to the search paths.

Comment: I just changed the 2.0.1 Pixate podspec to include PrivateHeaders as part of CocoaPods. For future releases, the Pixate team should exclude dependencies to Private headers from the Public ones.

Answer (score 2):

That header, `PXVirtualControl.h`, is included in the `PrivateHeaders` folder of the framework. You may need to add that folder in the header search path of your unit testing project.